# problem in the calculation of pressure drop for an axial turbine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, turbines, cfd

I am simulating an axial turbine. In this turbine, there are two domains.

The first domain is the piping before and after the blade and the second domain contains the turbine blades. The domain containing the blades rotates at 2000 rpm=209.43 rad/s while the other one is stationary.

[image]

There three pair of rotational periodic faces in numerical model( one is for inlet stationary domain and other one is outlet stationary domain and other one is for rotation domain). In fact, there are three pairs faces parallel to each other.

I validated torque of turbine with experimental values but pressure drop at inlet and outlet of turbine doesn't validate with experimental value correctly. In fact, pressure drop is law and it should be higher. How do i solve this problem?

I am grateful that guide me about this case.

Comment: What boundary conditions are you using (particularly at the inlet and outlet)?